# Running a timer for few minutes in python

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, python-multithreading

I am trying to run a certain function "foo" every second. I have to do this for a few minutes (say 5).

The function foo() makes 100 HTTP Requests (which contains a JSON object) to the server and prints the JSON response.

In short, I have to make 100 HTTP requests per second for 5 minutes.

I have just started learning python, thus don't have extensive knowledge. This is what I have tried:

```
import threading
noOfSecondsPassed = 0
def foo():
   global noOfSecondsPassed
   # piece of code which makes 100 HTTP requests (I use while loop)
   noOfSecondsPassed += 1

while True:
   if noOfSecondsPassed < (300)  # 5 minutes
       t = threading.Timer(1.0, foo)
       t.start()
```

Due to multiple threads, the function foo isn't called 300 times but much much more than that.
I have tried setting a lock too:

```
def foo():
  l = threading.Lock()
  l.acquire()
  global noOfSecondsPassed
  # piece of code which makes 100 HTTP requests (I use while loop)
  noOfSecondsPassed += 1
  l.release()
```

Rest of code is same as the previous code snippet. But this also does not work.

How do I do this?

**Edit: Different Approach**

I have tried this approach which worked for me:

```
def foo():
    noOfSecondsPassed = 0
    while noOfSecondsPassed < 300:
       #Code to make 100 HTTP requests
       noOfSecondsPassed +=1
       time.sleep(1.0)
foo()
```

Any disadvantages in doing so?

Comment: Have you considered a shell script that fires off a background process every second that performs the requests, for a total of 60*5=300 times? Saves you the hassle of using multiple threads.

Comment: @Evert No I haven't. I am not sure how to do that. I'll give it a try. Thanx.

Comment: arent't you supposed to compare noOfSecondsPassed rather than noOfSeconds, to begin with?

Comment: By the way, `urllib` is not thread safe.

Comment: For me, on Linux, it's as simple as `#! /bin/bash\nfor i in \`seq 300\`\ndo\n./fetch_urls.py &\nsleep 1\ndone\n`. I've put newlines there explicitly: a one-liner gets messed up easily by the `&`.

Comment: @njzk2 Sorry. That was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another approach which is easier I think.

Create 300 timer thread, each running 1 sec after the previous. The main loop is executed in almost an instant so the error factor is very low.
Here's a sample Demo:

```
import datetime
import thread
import threading

def foo():
     print datetime.datetime.now()
     print threading.active_count()

for x in range(0,300): 
     t = threading.Timer(x + 1, foo)
     t.start()
```

This code output should look like this:

```
2012-10-01 13:21:07.328029
301
2012-10-01 13:21:08.328281
300
2012-10-01 13:21:09.328449
299
2012-10-01 13:21:10.328615
298
2012-10-01 13:21:11.328768
297
2012-10-01 13:21:12.329006
296
2012-10-01 13:21:13.329289
295
2012-10-01 13:21:14.329369
294
2012-10-01 13:21:15.329580
293
2012-10-01 13:21:16.329793
292
2012-10-01 13:21:17.329958
291
2012-10-01 13:21:18.330138
290
2012-10-01 13:21:19.330300                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
289                         
...
```

As you can see, each thread is launched about 1 sec after the previous and you are starting exactly 300 threads.

Comment: This was helpful. But I tried another approach which worked for me (posted below). Sorry can't up-vote your answer due to lack of reputation score. Thanx :)

Comment: Couldn't post my approach as an answer. Edited my question and added there.