# Executing a function with threading.Timer with conditions

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-multithreading

I want to execute `getData` function each 1 second only for 60 iteration and after that I want to execute `foo` function.

```
def getDate():
    q = client.getQuotes(['EURUSD'])
    print q
```

I know how to run it each 1 second time (with threading.Timer), but I couldn't find out how to do it for certain iteration and also wait for function iteration to be finished `timer.join()`

Comment: Not sure what you are asking. Please explain what ` I couldn't find out how to do it for certain iteration` means. What is `it` that you couldn't find out how to do? You seem to know how to start the timers and how to wait for them (timer.join()), so I cannot tell what you are missing. Perhaps including more code would clarify.

Comment: I want to run `getDate` function each 1 second only for 60 iterations. How can I run it for 60 times? with interval of 1 second.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Running a timer for few minutes in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672750/running-a-timer-for-few-minutes-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
import threading
import time

ITERATIONS = 60

# this could be any function
def afunc(t):
    # the 't' argument is just to clarify the output
    for i in range(2):
        print('in timer #' + str(t) + ': ' + str(i))
        time.sleep(0.2)

timers = []
for t in range(ITERATIONS):
    # create a timer for this iteration (note the interval will be from 1.0 to the number of iterations)
    ti = threading.Timer(1.0 + t, afunc, args=[t])
    # save the timer in a list
    timers.append(ti)
    # start the timer
    ti.start()

# wait for them all
for ti in timers:
    ti.join()

print( 'all finished, call any other method here')
```